# Excel: Sum all numbers separated by new line within cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, newlines

[image]

How do I create a new cell that equals the sum all numbers in a cell separated by a new line?

I may not use text to columns as that is messy and there's no new line separator delimiter in text to columns in Excel and that's extra overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, you asked "does this work on an apple".

Mac computers do not have the `FILTERXML` function.

However, we can substitute:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99),0))
```

or, if you have the `NUMBERVALUE` function:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99)))
```

where `seq` is a defined **NAME** referring to:

```
=ROW(INDEX(Sheet16!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet16!$A:$A,255))
```

[image]

In the above we

- Replace each `lf` with `99` spaces
- Use the `MID` function to return an array of the values in the cell
- Convert those values to their numeric equivalent with either the `NUMBERVALUE` function; or using a double-unary.

  - *Since the double-unary will => error when applied to an empty string, we need to test for that with `IFERROR`.*
  - *That is not an issue if we use `NUMBERVALUE` which returns `0` when applied to an empty string.*
- `SUM` the values in the resultant array

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to correctly calculate with these values, is to first merge 'm to cells with Text to columns. I found a nice way to do this

- Select your cell and choose [Data] > Text to Columns
- Choose for "Delimited" and hit next
- Select "other" and in the empty textbox, press CTRL + J (nothing will
  appear)
- Hit finish and your data will be spread horizontally over the cells.

Now you can just do a sum like =SUM(2:2)

Comment: does this work on an apple?

Answer (score 0):

The macro below will get the sum you want.
Just select the cell below the one you want to get sum of.  Then call this macro.  It will write the sum in selected cell.  See the sample below:

[image]

```
Sub getsum_fromcell()
Dim newarr As Variant
mycell = Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, ActiveCell.Column)

newarr = Split(mycell, Chr(10))
                    mysum = 0
                    ubnd = UBound(newarr)
                    For i = 0 To ubnd
                        mysum = mysum + newarr(i)
                    Next i
ActiveCell.Value = mysum
End Sub
```

I am also pasting below the function version, in which you can get sum of any cell you will give to the function.

```
Function getsum_fromcell_func(mycell)
Dim newarr As Variant
newarr = Split(mycell, Chr(10))
                    mysum = 0
                    ubnd = UBound(newarr)
                    For i = 0 To ubnd
                        mysum = mysum + newarr(i)
                    Next i
getsum_fromcell_func = mysum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can achieve this within one cell and without any macros.

Assuming your source data is in cell A2 like in your screenshot:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<x><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), "</y><y>") & "</y></x>", "//y"))
```

This is an array formula, so you have to finish entering it with `ctrl + shift + enter` for it to work properly.

How does this formula work? With a little trick:

1. First it replaces all linebreaks in your data with the string `</y><y>`.
2. It encloses the new string with `<x><y>` and `</x></y>`, creating a valid xml table.
3. `FILTERXML` converts the xml table into a data array.
4. Finally it sums up all numbers from the array.

With this you should be good. Your data can even contain text lines, the formula will simply ignore all text.

**EDIT:** According to the documentation, the function FILTERXML is currently not available in Excel for the web and Excel for Mac.

Comment: Ah, I had started writing my answer and then a meeting caused delay. FWIW, you don't need to enter it as an array formula. You can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You mention the versions it won't work on but you could also mention those where it *does* work: Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel 2019, Excel 2016, or Excel 2013. Also, OP: You may use commas `,` in between function arguments whereas Matle uses semicolons `;`. If you copy / paste their formula and it doesn't work, that may be why.

Comment: You are correct. I'm using a european version that separates parameters with semicolon, in the american version these need to be commas. I adjusted the answer.
Regarding array formula, I tested and can confirm, the formula needs to be an array. Otherwise it will only sum the first figure and nothing else.

Comment: The array formula is interesting because it is not required on mine. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcZ8m.png)) I'm on Office 365, Excel version 2107 and the region as United States.

Comment: Now that's funny. On my Excel 2016 pro German version it will produce a wrong result as simple formula, but a correct one as array. [Screenshot simple vs. array formula](https://imgur.com/a/IUyp75c)
If you really don't like array formulas, you can still use `SUMPRODUCT` which will work as simple formula, but since most people understand whot `SUM` does, I'd rather stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel 2019, Excel 2016, or Excel 2013:

You can perform this formulaically with the very useful `FILTERXML()`.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<a><z>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"
","</z><z>")&"</z></a>","//z"))
```

Note that this is two lines long because of the literal line break in there. You could replace that with `CHAR(10)` (the ASCII equivalent) to make it one line.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<a><z>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</z><z>")&"</z></a>","//z"))
```

I won't pretend to understand everything about `FILTERXML()` because I've only ever used it to turn a string into an array. However, that's exactly what you need. My understanding is that it interprets text as XML data and then tries to display that data the way it would look in a browser or other software meant to display XML data. By wrapping your text in XML tags and replacing the line breaks with tags, you can make it look like XML data which Excel happily displays as several individual cells instead. You can wrap all that in a `SUM()` function since that's the result you want.

[image: Screenshot]